# JQuery click and hover doesn't work on div

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a div declared as follow, but the click event doesn't work.
I also need to use the :hover event in the css, but it doesn't work as well.
What's the problem ?

```
<div id="info-button" class="info-button"></div>
```

the css

```
.info-button {
    position:absolute;
    top:-200px;
    left:50px;
    background-image: url('../img/info-icon.png');
    background-size: 100%;
    background-position: 0px 0px;
    width: 89px !important;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 89px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

JQuery

```
$("#info-button").click(function() {
    alert("click");  
});
```

I also tried

```
$("#info-button").on("click", function () {
    alert("click");
});
```

Comment: Any errors in the console?

Comment: Are you registering click event in (document).ready or not ?

Comment: have you import jQuery Library ?

Comment: $(function(){
  $("#info-button").click(function() {
    alert("click");  
  });  
    
});

Comment: Your code **works**.

Error is **elsewhere**.

CSS Hover needs :

  `'.info-button:hover {     background-color:blue;}`

Comment: i think problem in main jq.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be sure to put your code inside document.ready

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
   $("#info-button").click(function() {
    alert("click");  
    });
});
```

And include properly your script in your HTML document after Jquery, example:

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/your_script.js"></script>
```

Comment: Based on placement of code, `document.ready` is not requirement, unless code is defined before the BODY itself

Comment: The problem was the document.ready ! Incredible. But the mouse hover event in the css doesn't work anyway. Another kind of problem for sure but I haven't solved it yet.

Answer (score 1):

Works perfectly fine. See the JSBin.

http://jsbin.com/lusiyalusu/edit?html,js,output

EDIT: Just saw you CSS, I think your DIV might be drawing outside the body, if its parent DIV. You've `top` set to `negative` value in `absolute` postioning.

```
.info-button {
    position:absolute;
    top:-200px;
    left:50px;
    background-image: url('../img/info-icon.png');
    background-size: 100%;
    background-position: 0px 0px;
    width: 89px !important;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 89px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

You can check if this is the case

Comment: then you must not include JavaScript before body, it's blocking and essentially bad practise to do

Answer (score 0):

Working Example

```js
$("#info-button").click(function() {
    alert("click");  
});
$("#info-hover").hover(function() {
    alert("hover");  
});
```

```css
.info-button {
    background-color: #f0f0f0;
    background-image: url("../img/info-icon.png");
    background-position: 0 0;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% auto;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 89px;
    
    
    width: 89px !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="info-button" class="info-button"></div>

<div id="info-hover" class="info-button"></div>
```